# Linear Discriminant Analysis for newbie (What is the meaning of dataset is linear separable?)

Tags: machine-learning, linear-model, linear, dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

What is the meaning of "LDA dataset is linear separable"?

"the classes are non-linearly separated"

"the features have nonlinear relationships"

As I know in maths for linear equation and non-linear equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the classes are linearly separable, there exists a hyperplane (on the same feature space) to separate them. When there is not, the classes are either non-separable or separated by other types of hyper-surfaces, e.g. if instead of a line, a parabola in 2D feature space can separate the classes, it's said non-linearly separable. Features having non-linear relationships is like having features $x,y$ where $y=x^2$. When you add new features using the old ones, to be able to separate your samples in a higher dimensional space linearly (so non-linearly in the original feature space), you add new features that are nonlinearly related to the original ones.

Comment: thanks. I am confused with the sentences `When you add new features using the old ones, to be able to separate your samples in a higher dimensional space linearly`. What is the `old one`?

Comment: original features.

Comment: thanks. So  `When you add new features using the original features`, this situation is not suitable if I use LDA as `dimensional reduction method`. Adding new features using old features is like making a new prediction?

Comment: Still, you could do the LDA in the new feature space.

Comment: thanks. Are you familiar with `LDA, small sample size problem`?  I would be appreciated if you can give some comment/answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468095/linear-discriminant-analysis-have-small-sample-size-problem-sss-is-it-nd

Comment: Is it true that `LDA is not capable of dealing with features which have non-linear relationships`?

Comment: LDA is not handling features, it handles the classes. Features can surely have nonlinear relationships. For example, we can add a new feature $x^2$ that makes the classes more separable, which means LDA will do a good job.

Comment: thanks. Maybe I read somewhere which I am confused / I make mistake. How about `LDA is not capable of dealing with classes which have non-linear relationships`?

Comment: I'd say 'classes which have non-linear decision boundaries'

Comment: thanks. You are brilliant! Can you read this sentence, make sense? `the classes of both datasets are not linearly separable in the original feature space. LDA fails to find the projection defining LDA space when the discriminatory information does not lie in the means of classes. Although the LDA method can effectively reduce the dimension of a dataset, it is not capable of dealing with classes which have non-linear decision boundaries because the LDA method requires the input data to have the property of linearity.`

Comment: generally makes sense, and better to stay in your own words. I'd soften the statements a bit, e.g. LDA is less capable ... because ... requires the class separators to be hyperplanes.

Comment: thanks a lot. Brillant!

Comment: Is Linear Discriminate Analysis (LDA) and Fisher Discriminant Analysis (FDA) same meaning?

And also Fisher Criterion (FC)?

Do these three terms interchangeably, having the same meaning?

Comment: there are slight differences in some contexts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#/Fisher's_linear_discriminant

Comment: Linear discriminant analysis (LDA)  is a generalization of Fisher's linear discriminant.  The terms Fisher's linear discriminant and LDA are often used interchangeably, although Fisher's original article[1] actually describes a slightly different discriminant

I think is same meaning